# Start Meteor Build

Tags: meteor

After build my Meteor APP, i would like start this with NodeJS.

I go to my `/build/` folder, and run `node main.js` but i've this error :

> Error: Cannot find module 'fibers'

```
Error: Cannot find module 'fibers'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\wamp\www\www.meteor.lan\build\app\bundle\programs\server\boot.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
```

I'm use Meteor 1.4 and Node 4.4.7 on Windows.

Do you have any idea how i can start my Meteor APP after build ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to install all packages, not just `fibers`. Inside you build directory:

```
cd programs\server
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `npm install fibers`